# Invalid value for <circle> attribute c(x/y) ="NaN"

Tags: javascript, django, csv, d3.js

I have a python background but no experience with javascript.
I am trying to learn d3.js to use it with django.

I want to reproduce this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3183403) but it simply won't work and I get an empty plot with error:

**error message**

> Invalid value for  attribute cx="NaN"
>
> Invalid value for  attribute cy="NaN"

In this example, data is loaded from `data.csv` file that I placed in the same directory with my `index.html` file.

**view**

```py
def first_case(request):
    template = loader.get_template('usecases/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.point {
  stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // Compute the series names ("y1", "y2", etc.) from the loaded CSV.
  var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0])
      .filter(function(d) { return d !== "x"; })
      .sort();

  // Map the data to an array of arrays of {x, y} tuples.
  var series = seriesNames.map(function(series) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: +d.x, y: +d[series]};
    });
  });

  // Compute the scales’ domains.
  x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

  // Add the x-axis.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

  // Add the y-axis.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

  // Add the points!
  svg.selectAll(".series")
      .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "series")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .selectAll(".point")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "point")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); });
});

</script>
```

**Data.csv**

```py
x,y1,y2
5,90,22
25,30,25
45,50,80
65,55,9
85,25,95
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I am suspecting that data.csv is not reachable as it give the same error if I change data.csv to anything else.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks for considering my lack of experience with javascript and d3.js

Comment: There is obviously a problem with your `d.x` values, maybe the csv is not formatted properly, could be the newline characters are spaces?

Comment: @CoolBlue data.csv is looking good. I am suspecting that data.csv is not reachable as it give the same error if I change `data.csv` to anything else.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I wrote my comment prior to your edit where cy was added. Definitely a problem with the data. Is this throwing: `if (error) throw error;`?  If not some other subtle formatting issue with the data is messing up the parsing I guess.

Comment: @CoolBlue there is no errors, only an empty graph..

Comment: Have you traced it in the console? What do the data array elements look like? I know you're new to JS, can you post a working version? In a public folder in dropbox or something?

Comment: @CoolBlue  The only data is he data of the csv file. Sorry I don't know how to trace it in the console, can you tell me how?

Comment: Well... in chrome for example, right click and select inspect elements.  You should be able to figure it out from there... But it would be better to post a working example somewhere...

Comment: Is your file "Data.csv" or "data.csv"?  Your JS says "data", your post is "Data", I believe Django's built in web server is case sensitive.  Regardless, here's a quick JS debug lesson:  1, do all your JavaScript debugging with Chrome.  2, open your page in chrome and then press F12 to open the developer tools.  3, click "Console", what errors are there?  Was your page able to load "data.csv"?  I'm guessing it 404ed.